# Force https for all server blocks in https context

Tags: docker, nginx, proxypass

I'm trying nginx for first time, and I do it with docker.
Basically I want to achieve the following architecture

- https://example.com (business webiste`)
- https://app.example.com (*progressive web* / *single page* app)
- https://app.example.com/api (to avoid preflight requests, a proxy to https://api.example.com is needed)
- https://api.example.com (restful api)
- Every `http` request to be redirected to `https`

I'm generating the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` file with some environment variables on start up. That file is then included inside the `http` context of the default.conf file, thus bringing some limitation to what I can configure. ([related issue](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/issues/247))

You can see my current [**`nginx.conf` file here**](https://gist.github.com/Frondor/e02a124e2ceedf10e11ee9f14cf905bf) (file is quite large to embed here).

And you can see the [`docker-compose.yml` file here](https://github.com/dockerizate/docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml).

### The problem:

#### 400 Bad Request The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

I can't actually make that any call to `http://(app/api).example.com` to be redirected to its `https` version, I've tried with this without success: (see the the above linked file)

```
server {
    listen 80 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:80 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name  api.dev.local;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    # more code...
}
```

Any recommendations regarding to the my actual configs are more than welcome in the comments sections! I'm just starting to use nginx and thus reading [tons of artciles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFpe6.png) that provide code snippets that I simply copy and paste after reading what are they needed for.

Comment: `https` is an extension to `http` so it is to an extent a different protocol. Your server does not expect `http` on :80, it expects `https` (with `listen 80 ssl`), therefore, the error. You need to accept `http` on :80 and configure nginx to redirect all those requests to `https` on :443 Here is a link to help you with that https://bjornjohansen.no/redirect-to-https-with-nginx

Comment: @OlegSklyar so another server block listening to port 80 and redirecting should do the job? Not a rewrite? Should I stop listening to both 80 and 443 in the same server block?

Comment: I'd say yes, you need another block for plain http and :80 doing a simple redirect, that is returning 3xx and the https url. In the current block you should only leave :443 and https but no :80. Pretty much as described under the link

Comment: Tip: by using `caddy` in place of `nginx` you will get all of that for free including automatic and free certification via Let's Encrypt. This maybe not an ideal solution for a big enterprise, but is a good option for a single app or a beta-release

Comment: @OlegSklyar Oh, caddy looks really promising! I'll give it a try for sure. Thank you very much! You can formulate an answer referencing the approach in that article and I'll give you the credit for it. It worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `https` protocol is an extension to `http`, so they are *different* protocols to an extent. At the moment your server does not expect `http` on :80, it rather expects `https` due to the setting `listen 80 ssl`. This causes the error.

You need to separate handling of `http` requests on :80, which should be redirected to `https` on :443, from handling `https` on :443, which should be handled normally.

This can be done by splitting out another `server` configuration block for `http` on :80:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

...and removing listening on :80 from the current block:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    # more code...
}
```

The following blog article gives more details if needed https://bjornjohansen.no/redirect-to-https-with-nginx